# How to see Tomcat page in localhost after IIS configuration

Tags: tomcat, iis

A few days ago I configured IIS on the virtual machine where I'm working on and today I tried to go on localhost. I expected to see the tomcat page, instead I see the IIS page.
I need the Tomcat's because I'm used a tool I first deployed with Tomcat and I can access it only by "localhost/ThingWorx/" but if I do this url, I get a 404 error.
Can you tell me if it is possible to see again the tomncat page without cancell IIS?

Comment: Are both Tomcat and IIS trying to listen on the same port?

Comment: It purely depends on how you set them up. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manjug/2015/11/27/understanding-iis-httpplatformhandler-using-tomcat-8/